# Error: Already loaded patch: ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular5, angular-universal, zonejs

We try to make server side render build for Angular 5 project, then it shows this error. Zone js is loaded on my `polyfills.ts` , What the problem how to fix it.

And i observe same Zone code in twice in mys `server.js` file, thanks

```
Error: Already loaded patch: ZoneAwarePromise
    at E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:628850:6
    at FUNCTION (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:628213:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:628216:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:372510:30)
```